# Clarification on matrix encoding linear map.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

I am reading Tim Gowers's article [here](https://www.dpmms.cam.ac.uk/%7Ewtg10/tensors3.html) on tensor products. Here is an excerpt from it that gave me confusion.

> For example, if $f:V \to W$ is a linear map between finite-dimensional vector spaces $V$ and $W$, then one thing we like to do is encode it using a collection of numbers. The usual way to do this is to take bases of $V$ and $W$ and define a matrix $A$. To obtain the $j$th column of this matrix, one takes the $j$th basis vector $e_j$ of $V$, writes $f(e_j)$ as a linear combination of the vectors in the basis of W, and uses those coefficients.
>
> The reason that the matrix encodes the linear map is that if you know $f(e_j)$ for every $j$ then you know $f$: if $v$ is a linear combination of the $e_j$ then $f(v)$ is the corresponding linear combination of the $f(e_j)$.

Could anybody supply a bit more detail/explain what is going on here a bit more in depth? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a basis $\{v_1,\ldots,v_n\}$ for $V$ and $\{w_1,\ldots,w_m\}$ for $W$. For each $j=1,\ldots,n$, I want to compute $f(v_j)\in W$. It is natural to write $f(v_j)$ in the chosen basis for $W$. In order to do this, I end up needing a pair of subscripts for the coefficients of the $w_i$:
$$f(v_j)=\sum_{i=1}^ma_{ij}w_i.$$
This yields a matrix $A=(a_{ij})$ which completely determines the linear transformation $f$. Indeed, write any $v\in V$ as $v=\sum_{j=1}^n\lambda_jv_j$. The
$$
\begin{align}
f(v)&=f\left(\sum_j\lambda_jv_j\right)\\
&=\sum_j\lambda_jf(v_j)\\
&=\sum_j\sum_i\lambda_ja_{ij}w_i.
\end{align}
$$

It is also a useful exercise to see matrix multiplication as a composition of functions in this way. Take a map $g:U\to V$, choose a basis $\{u_1,\ldots,u_\ell\}$ for $U$ and compute $(f\circ g)(u_k)$ given that
$$g(u_k)=\sum_j b_{jk}v_j.$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $\vec v\in V, \vec w\in W$. Fix a basis $\vec a_1,\ldots,\vec a_n$ in $V$, and a basis $\vec b_1,\ldots,\vec b_m$ in $V$.

What basis do for vectors? **It convert abstract vectors to sequences of real numbers.** After that we can work with the numbers (called *coordinates*) instead of vectors itself.

---

Now take a linear map $f:V\to W$, it can be expressed using the bases:
$$f(\vec v,\vec w)=f(v_1 \vec a_1+\cdots+v_n \vec a_n,w_1 \vec b_1 +\cdots+w_n \vec b_m)=\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^m f_{ij}\, v_i\, w_i$$
where
$$f_{ij}:=f(\vec a_i,\vec b_j)$$

So, what basis do for linear maps? **It convert an abstract linear map to a array of real numbers.** Note that we can write the array as a $n\times m$ table. The table is called the matrix of $f$ in given bases.

---

A bit more deeper? If we have a $(p,q)$-type tensor on $V$ and have fixed a basis here, the basis can naturally **convert this abstract tensor to a $(p+q)$-dimensional array of real numbers.** Note that vectors are $(1,0)$ tensors, linear maps are $(1,1)$ tensors.